# Manipulating client DOM from the server

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, websocket

I there any Javascript library that enables the server to edit the client DOM easily, through AJAX or Websocket?

It would allow me to write the whole code in a single language (Python) instead of two (Python and Javascript).